# Why public Electrum servers serving on websocket (WS) are so rare?

Tags: electrum, websockets

Couldn't find a single one. Only TCP or TLS.
Am I looking in the wrong place? ( https://1209k.com/bitcoin-eye/ele.php?chain=btc )

Answer (score 1):

They are rare because Electrum and all the other wallets using the protocol do not support it client-side, so nobody setting up an ElectrumX server has any incentive to enable this. ElectrumX requires you to enable individual protocols explicitly. Furthermore, as you can see in [the changelog](https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx/blob/7e37f3b0537f4ffe6724e07939e58fe71dbd56d2/docs/changelog.rst#version-1120-13-may-2019) they have only been supported since May 2019.